# Flex TextInput prompts and Button labels disappearing with layoutDirection="rtl"

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I'm building a mobile app for Android and iOS which needs to support both RTL and LTR text, for Hebrew and English. The problem is that when I use the layoutDirection="rtl", the prompt text in my TextInputs and the labels on my Buttons disappear.

And if that weren't enough, even if I don't change layoutDirection, the RTL text appears backwards on my Android phone (I haven't tested on iOS), even though it's fine on the AIR emulator. And the text in the TextInput is fine, just not the prompt.

With both of these problems, it's completely fine in Spark Label controls, so I assume there's something different with the TextInput prompts and Button labels, but I'm not sure what.

What is going on here?

TYIA